# windows phone page initialization using async method error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, async-await

I have Windows phone page that fetch data from the web url using async. In my page class consructor I cannot call a async method. How do I initialize properties from the web url repsonse in the constructor.

```
public MyProfile()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _populateFields();
}

private async void _populateFields()
{
    try
    {
        var taskObj = await UserProfile.getUserProfile().getUserProfileFromServer();
        //PoolCircle.UserProfile.ProfileResponseJson userObj = taskObj;
        setDataContext(taskObj);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
}
```

How do I fix this dependency? I am not sure how a factory method fix it. I am not creating object for the page class..

Comment: What is the issue here exactly? Won't compile? Won't run? Crashes? Also, **never write async void**, use `async Task` and rename method to `PopulateFieldsAsync`.

Comment: actually it I thought I cannot call a async void mehtod from a constructor but it works...

Comment: You can always call async methods, there are no restrictions on where you can call them from.

Comment: You might want to read [Stephen Cleary's article on this topic](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html).

Answer (score -1):

Try it from the OnNavigatedTo method. Overriding it. Its a method who you can put all your logic before the page appears

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    _populateFields();
}
```

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedto%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

hope helps! Greetings!

Answer (score -1):

Make a method like `PostData();` and call this after `InitializeComponent();`

```
private async void PostData()
{
    try
    {
        var taskObj = await UserProfile.getUserProfile().getUserProfileFromServer();
        //PoolCircle.UserProfile.ProfileResponseJson userObj = taskObj;
        setDataContext(taskObj);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
}
```

Comment: You are giving the same method. Only Changing the name. I doesn't know what's the difference from the question code. greetings.

Comment: Same comment as above: add sufix Async and change the return type.

Comment: What is reason behind suffixing Async? Does it tell anything to compiler or just best practice? Return type I can understand.